# web3js sender account not recognized

Tags: private-blockchain, accounts, external-api, ganache

Under Ganache, I created some APIs with nodejs to managing a Smart Contract. One API is for the creation of new accounts with

```
newAccount = web3.eth.accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32));
```

Then, with another API, when I try to access a function of the Smart Contract with

```
contractInstance.methods.myFunction(param1, param2, param3).send({
from: newAccount.address,
gas: 4600000
}).on('transactionHash', function(hash){
console.log(hash);
}).on('error', console.error);
});
```

the transaction fails with the error

```
sender account not recognized
```

Where am I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: did my answer worked for you?. I am curious.

Answer (score 3):

Probably after creating the account in the way you do, your new address is not returned when you do `web3.eth.getAccounts()` because this creates an account that is not associated with your node.

Use instead `web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password, [callback])`

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there a way to specify our own public and private key while using  `web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password, [callback])` ?